# How to connect DevTools to Dart or Flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to profile CPU in a Flutter unit test. How can I connect Dart DevTools to the test?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `fluter test` run `flutter run  -d flutter-tester --start-paused <path to the test file>`.

Then connect the printed URL to the DevTools.